# pip install fails when pinned to a specific version (django-reversetag)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I have a bunch of packages in my `req.txt`, which I normally install on all my environments by simply using:

```
pip install -r req.txt
```

Now, one line of this `req` file has:

```
django-reversetag==0.3.2
```

Today, when I was doing a regular install, I surprisingly got this message:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo/ve/sport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/foo/ve/sport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/home/foo/ve/sport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1197, in prepare_files
    do_download,
  File "/home/foo/ve/sport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1375, in unpack_url
    self.session,
  File "/home/foo/ve/sport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 546, in unpack_http_url
    resp = session.get(target_url, stream=True)
  File "/home/foo/ve/sport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/foo/ve/sport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 237, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/foo/ve/sport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 456, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/foo/ve/sport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 559, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/foo/ve/sport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 375, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/source/d/django-reversetag/django-reversetag-0.3.2.tar.gz (Caused by <class 'httplib.BadStatusLine'>: '')
```

However, when I simply change:

```
django-reversetag==0.3.2
```

to,

```
django-reversetag
```

..everything seems fine... which I think is bizarre. I was always told to pin the package to a specific version.

I have no clue why this is failing.. and I have around 15 projects using the same req file..

Any ideas why this is happening.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of pip?

Comment: `pip 1.5.6` on my virtual environment - Would be nice if someone could try installing the same package (django-reversetag==0.3.2) and show output!

Comment: installs fine for me, try updating to latest pip which is 6.0.6 ,  I have seen a couple of strange issues  that were fixed by updating https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Comment: I upgraded pip as you said and it works perfectly fine. Now my pip is on `6.0..6` - this is a weird problem! Please post this as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks again for all your help - would have never thought pip itself was to blame for it!

Comment: no worries,  I added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been a few strange errors with pip where upgrading to the latest version [6.0.6](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) has been the solution